# Vulkan is failing on linux with BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gpu, xorg, optimus

Anything based on Vulkan fails on start.
The system is Arch Linux, with X11 and KDE.
Bumblebee (optirun) works as expected with OpenGL, and does not fail.
Without optirun, Vulkan fails, as integrated video card (or driver, mesa) does not seem support it.
With optirun the following result is received

```
$ optirun -vv vulkaninfo
[124888.207097] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[124888.208006] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[124888.208080] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[124888.208090] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[124888.208106] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[124888.208130] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia:/usr/lib32/nvidia:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32
[124888.208158] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[124888.208180] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[124888.208194] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[124888.208207] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[124888.208220] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/primus:/usr/lib32/primus
[124888.208375] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge virtualgl
[124889.370796] [INFO]Response: Yes. X is active.

[124889.370808] [INFO]Running application using virtualgl.
[124889.370905] [DEBUG]Process vglrun started, PID 19159.
X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (X_GLXQueryVersion)
  Serial number of failed request:  9
  Current serial number in output stream:  9
[124889.595290] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[124889.595308] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[124889.595321] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

Some info about system

```
$ optirun --version
optirun (Bumblebee) 3.2.1

$ pacaur -Qi vulkan-tools 
Name            : vulkan-tools
Version         : 1.1.114-1

$ pacaur -Qi xorg-server 
Name            : xorg-server
Version         : 1.20.5-2
```

Info from journalctl

```
Aug 11 18:02:34 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: Unhandled client message:  "_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54472, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54473, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54474, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54475, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54476, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54477, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54478, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 54479, resource id: 0, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code: 0
Aug 11 18:02:37 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: Unhandled client message:  "_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
Aug 11 18:02:45 OrestArch wpa_supplicant[591]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Aug 11 18:03:13 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: Unhandled client message:  "_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
Aug 11 18:03:14 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: Unhandled client message:  "_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
Aug 11 18:03:17 OrestArch kwin_x11[831]: qt.qpa.xcb: Unhandled client message:  "_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
Aug 11 18:03:51 OrestArch kernel: bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
Aug 11 18:03:51 OrestArch kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
Aug 11 18:03:51 OrestArch kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  430.40  Sun Jul 21 04:53:48 CDT 2019
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  430.40  Sun Jul 21 04:57:42 CDT 2019
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch bumblebeed[571]: [127184.603240] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch bumblebeed[571]: [127184.603253] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mouse
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch bumblebeed[571]: [127184.603261] [WARN][XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch bumblebeed[571]: [127184.603265] [WARN][XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" is not used
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch bumblebeed[571]: [127184.603272] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mouse
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch bumblebeed[571]: [127184.603276] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) PreInit returned 2 for "<default pointer>"
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch bumblebeed[571]: [127184.603280] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) PreInit returned 2 for "<default keyboard>"
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch audit[21655]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 pid=21655 comm="vulkaninfo" exe="/usr/bin/vulkaninfo" sig=11 res=1
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch kernel: vulkaninfo[21655]: segfault at 10 ip 00007fc63ce62d14 sp 00007ffe39105e58 error 4 in libpthread-2.29.so[7fc63ce5e000+f000]
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch kernel: Code: ff 48 8d 0d 6e a9 00 00 ba 4f 02 00 00 48 8d 35 f7 a7 00 00 48 8d 3d 0d a8 00 00 e8 46 ba ff ff 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa <8b> 47 10 49 89 f8 89 c2 81 e2 7f 01 00 00 83 e0 7c 0f 85 a5 00 00
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch kernel: audit: type=1701 audit(1565535832.160:209): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 pid=21655 comm="vulkaninfo" exe="/usr/bin/vulkaninfo" sig=11 res=1
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 21664/UID 0).
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-coredump@13-21664-0.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit systemd-coredump@13-21664-0.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 5178.
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-coredump@13-21664-0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1565535832.166:210): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-coredump@13-21664-0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Aug 11 18:03:52 OrestArch systemd-coredump[21665]: Process 21655 (vulkaninfo) of user 1000 dumped core.

                                                   Stack trace of thread 21655:
                                                   #0  0x00007fc63ce62d14 __pthread_mutex_lock (libpthread.so.0)
                                                   #1  0x00007fc63b80e2cc n/a (libnvidia-glcore.so.430.40)
                                                   #2  0x00007fc63c967558 n/a (libGLX_nvidia.so.0)
                                                   #3  0x00007fc63c9621c9 n/a (libGLX_nvidia.so.0)
                                                   #4  0x00007fc63c9633d4 n/a (libGLX_nvidia.so.0)
                                                   #5  0x00007fc63d2363ca XCloseDisplay (libX11.so.6)
                                                   #6  0x00007fc63d3cb034 XCloseDisplay (libvglfaker.so)
                                                   #7  0x00007fc63c983fbf n/a (libGLX_nvidia.so.0)
                                                   #8  0x00007fc63d471b4d _dl_fini (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
                                                   #9  0x00007fc63d025e70 __run_exit_handlers (libc.so.6)
                                                   #10 0x00007fc63d025fae exit (libc.so.6)
                                                   #11 0x00007fc63d25b3d8 _XDefaultError (libX11.so.6)
                                                   #12 0x00007fc63d25b50a _XError (libX11.so.6)
                                                   #13 0x00007fc63d258398 n/a (libX11.so.6)
                                                   #14 0x00007fc63d259596 _XReply (libX11.so.6)
                                                   #15 0x00007fc63c960d92 n/a (libGLX_nvidia.so.0)
                                                   #16 0x00007fc63c98404a n/a (libGLX_nvidia.so.0)
                                                   #17 0x00007fc63c9843c9 vk_icdNegotiateLoaderICDInterfaceVersion (libGLX_nvidia.so.0)
                                                   #18 0x00007fc63d1d8216 n/a (libvulkan.so.1)
                                                   #19 0x00007fc63d1dce68 n/a (libvulkan.so.1)
                                                   #20 0x00007fc63d1de85e vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties (libvulkan.so.1)
                                                   #21 0x000056501afa4736 n/a (vulkaninfo)
                                                   #22 0x000056501af9e2e7 n/a (vulkaninfo)
                                                   #23 0x00007fc63d00fee3 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
                                                   #24 0x000056501afa0f2e n/a (vulkaninfo)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was installing the latest version of Nvidia drivers and `primus_vk`, as by default Bumblebee doesn't have Vulkan support.